# Powershell function to check input and return datatype is not returning correct values

Tags: powershell

I'm using a powershell script to assist with database updates/parsing/etc. Because our database servers do not allow us to do queries and updates within the same script, I need to actually query data, parse it on my computer with powershell, and then build a new update statement from the parsed query. In order to assist with this, I need to correctly cast datatypes between powershell and SQL. I wrote the following function to assist with this, but it is not correctly parsing timestamps, and any timestamp passed to it is causing the function to return 'string' and leave the $setDate variable as $null

```
$myDate = '5/10/2023'

function getDataType {
   param($inputData)
   
   #check if input data is null
   if (!$inputData) {
      return 'null'
   }
   
   #check if variable can be cast as a timestamp
   try {
      #build an array of possible timestamp formats
      $dateFormats = @('M/d/yyyy','M/dd/yyyy','MM/d/yyyy','MM/dd/yyyy','MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss','MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm','yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss')
      
      foreach ($format in $dateFormats) {
         if ([DateTime]::TryParseExact($inputData, $format, $null)) {
            $global:setDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($inputData, $format, $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
            return 'timestamp'
            break
         }
      }
   }
   catch {
      write-verbose 'not a timestamp'
   }
   
   #check if data is a number
   try {
      if ([int]$inputData) {
         return 'number'
      }
   }
   catch {
      write-verbose 'not a number'
   }
   
   #assumes input is a string if it is not null, not a date, and not a number
   return 'string'
}

getDataType($myDate) #should return 'timestamp' but returns 'string'

write-host "the date is $setDate" #should return "the date is 2023-05-10 00:00:00" but returns nothing
```

Comment: are you going to be using this logic repeatedly ? if so, I would recommend you to use a static class method instead of a function, repeated function calls are expensive. the main issue with your code is that your use `[DateTime]::TryParseExact` is incorrect and its throwing an error, you're just not seeing it because `write-verbose 'not a number'` doesn't have a `-Verbose` argument to produce verbose output.

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `getDataType $myDate` - _not_ like C# methods - `getDataType($myDate)`.  It happens to work with a _single_ argument, but breaks with multiple ones, because if you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that your use [`[DateTime]::TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-7.0) is incorrect and its throwing an error, you're just not seeing it because `Write-Verbose` doesn't have a `-Verbose` argument to produce verbose output, a minimal example:

```bash
try {
    [DateTime]::TryParseExact('5/10/2023', 'M/dd/yyyy', $null)
}
catch {
    Write-Verbose 'not a timestamp' -Verbose
}

# Outputs: VERBOSE: not a timestamp
```

It also seems you're looking to make repeated calls to this function, you should note that [repeated function calls is expensive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations?view=powershell-7.3#avoid-repeated-calls-to-a-function), for that I would recommend you to change your function for a [static method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-7.0) which don't suffer from this. Here is a working version of what you were looking to accomplish:

```bash
class MyType {
    static [string[]] $Formats = @(
        'M/d/yyyy'
        'M/dd/yyyy'
        'MM/d/yyyy'
        'MM/dd/yyyy'
        'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'
        'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm'
        'yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss'
    )

    static [string] GetDataType([object] $inputData, [ref] $out) {
        if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($inputData)) {
            return 'null or empty string'
        }

        if([int]::TryParse($inputData, [ref] $null)) {
            return 'its an integer'
        }

        # no need for a loop here, `TryParseExact` has an `string?[]? formats` overload for this ;)
        $isDate = [datetime]::TryParseExact(
            $inputData,
            [MyType]::Formats,
            [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture,
            [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, # You should define this one
            $out)

        if($isDate) {
            return 'its a datetime'
        }

        return 'undetermined string'
    }
}

$myDate = '5/10/2023'
$myOutVar = [datetime]::new(0)
$result = [MyType]::GetDataType($myDate, [ref] $myOutVar)

if($result -eq 'its a datetime') {
    return $myOutVar
}

$result
```

Comment: thanks! this is more or less exactly what I was looking for. I had realized after some more digging that I wasn't using TryParseExact correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to specify custom datetime formats, something like the Get-Date cmdlet should catch valid dates & timestamps. If you want to consider formats with periods that would fail with Get-Date, use a replace like so...

```
# Below example captured all dates in desired string format
$SetDates = @(
    '5/9/2023',
    '5/10/2023',
    '05/9/2023',
    '05/10/2023',
    '05-10-2023 12:05:02',
    '05-10-2023 12:05',
    '2023-05-10 12.05.02'
) | ForEach-Object { 
      Get-Date -Date $($_ -replace '\.',':') -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
}
```

$SetDates

```
2023-05-09 00:00:00
2023-05-10 00:00:00
2023-05-09 00:00:00
2023-05-10 00:00:00
2023-05-10 12:05:02
2023-05-10 12:05:00
2023-05-10 12:05:02
```